# MS Outlook contact search by Phone Number

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using the following example code to find a specific contact in Outlook:

```
string phoneNumber = "+4922334455";
Outlook.ContactItem contact;
contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)contactItems.Find(String.Format("[HomeTelephoneNumber]='{0}'", phoneNumber));
```

However I am having problems if the entry in Outlook is formatted (ex. +49 (2233) 4455 ).

How can I search for this number so that even formatted entries are matched? I wouldn't like to iterate through all contacts since it can take a long time if there are a lot of contacts.

---

Here is how `contactItems` is defined:

```
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace
    = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder contactsFolder
    = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Outlook.Items contactItems = contactsFolder.Items;
```

Comment: Sorry I ommitted the code before for simplicity.
`Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder contactsFolder =
                outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Outlook.Items contactItems = contactsFolder.Items;`